# How can I enter the dome of a Biolab?

Tags: planetside-2

Biolabs have control points within the top dome as well as on the ground *(small sattelite bases a few hundred meters away)*. How can I get into the top part of the base to capture these points? The only entrance seems to be at the bottom, but it's closed with shields. I can't pass when the base belongs to an enemy faction.

[image]

Answer (score 8):

You can't use the main entrance on the ground, but there are two other ways to enter. The first option is to use an aircraft and land at the pads of the base *(preferably with a Galaxy and some friends)*. There is a small entrance which can be passed by infantery that doesn't have any shields.

Or you can use one of the teleporters found at the small sattelite bases. They look similar to a spawning tube and are often found in a dedicated building. You must capture the point near them to make it accessible to your faction.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Along with [Alextsc's answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/82599/3996) there are some launchers that are on top of or around outlying buildings in the area that will sling you to the aircraft spawn points of the dome.

I'll post a pic of one later as I'm at work currently.